# AppSettingsSectionSettings based upon AppSettings

Tags: c#, web-config, servicestack

Can you guys add this into ServiceStack?  We mostly keep our settings in separate files as such;

```
<configSections>
  <section name="FluentFilter.AuthenticationActionFilterAttribute" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection, System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" />
</configSections>

<FluentFilter.AuthenticationActionFilterAttribute file="FluentFilter.AuthenticationActionFilterAttribute.config" />
```

Here is my config file:

```
<FluentFilter.AuthenticationActionFilterAttribute>
  <add key="RouteValueDictionary" value='{area:"Identity",controller:"auth",action:"logon",ServiceStackAuth:"/api/auth/googleopenid?Continue={0}"}' />
  <add key="Area" value='["Support","Sports"]' />
  <add key="FilterType" value="Pingo.Contrib.ServiceStack.Filters.AuthenticationActionFilterAttribute"/>
</FluentFilter.AuthenticationActionFilterAttribute>
```

and Finally, the AppSettingsSectionSettings based upon your AppSettings class.

```
/// <summary>
/// More familiar name for the new crowd.
/// </summary>
public class AppSettingsSectionSettings : AppSettingsBase
{
    private System.Configuration.Configuration _configuration;

    private class ConfigurationManagerWrapper : ISettings
    {
        private readonly AppSettingsSection _appSettingsSection;
        public ConfigurationManagerWrapper(AppSettingsSection appSettingsSection)
        {
            _appSettingsSection = appSettingsSection;
        }

        public string Get(string key)
        {
            return _appSettingsSection.Settings[key].Value;
        }
    }

    public AppSettingsSectionSettings(AppSettingsSection appSettingsSection)
        : base(new ConfigurationManagerWrapper(appSettingsSection))
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns string if exists, otherwise null
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string GetString(string name) //Keeping backwards compatible
    {
        return base.GetNullableString(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could submit a [pull request](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pulls), but it seems like a simple enough customization that it should live with your own code. If someone else is in the same situation, they will be able to search and find it here on StackOverflow.